# I want to remove the top and bottom black margin of youtube video

Tags: javascript, html, css, youtube

I want the video width=100% and height=500px(a fixed height). But I don't want the top & bottom black margin of the youtube video. And I have to make it responsive later. Is it possible?

```
<iframe width="100%" height="500px" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/T1mP3S4-o3c?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Add your code snippet it help to find where that space is coming.

Comment: Where are the codes ?

Comment: I have added the code @MerajKhan

Comment: so, you cant use absolute property of html right?

Comment: have a look at this also https://wistia.com/blog/remove-black-bars-from-online-video

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will show black margin if you want fixed height(500px as per question) in responsive too.

These black margin shows blank area left in video because of its resolution/proportion (for ex. 1920px*1080px or 1080px*720px).

You have to apply width and height as per its proportion to avoid these black margin.

**The best way is to use both width and height 100%.**

```css
* {padding:0;margin:0;box-sizing:border-box;}
.video {
 position: relative;
 padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
 height: 0;
}
.video iframe {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="video">
  <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/T1mP3S4-o3c?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: it remove left and right border. but in bottom there is a black border appeared. how to remove that border?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, according to your code body default margin is coming.If you want to remove write like this body {margin:0;padding:0;}

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<iframe width="100%" height="500px" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/T1mP3S4-o3c?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```